# How to terminate Django request handler on timeout

Tags: python, django

On a webpage I have a button which makes ajax request, on server side a library function is called, DB updated and page is reloaded on call success. If network connection is lost during library call, the handler never ends. I want to terminate and restart the library function processing on a subsequent button presses. What happens in framework in case of hanging handler? Should I run a separate thread/process and terminate it if needed? In the latter case how to pass call results to the page, after the process is done?
Edit: updated.

Comment: Just have a timeout for the request on the client side. You're probably getting this because of keep-alive connections.

Comment: How did you deploy your Django?

Comment: Klaus D., installed with pip, or what did you mean?

Comment: Games Brainiac, updated the question. The client works fine. I just wonder how to correctly handle request on the server side in case it takes too long.